# some troubles on installing deja-dup from source code

Tags: software-installation, make, source, cmake, pkg-config

*(Learning how to install programs on linux...)*

[deja-dup source code](https://gitlab.gnome.org/World/deja-dup) can be downloaded on its GitHub repo. There is a makefile con the package. Once into the folder I run:

```
santi@eoan:~/deja-dup$ make
```

And get the error:

```
The Meson build system

Project name: deja-dup
Project version: 40.6
...
   Run-time dependency goa-1.0 found: NO (tried pkgconfig and cmake)
    Run-time dependency json-glib-1.0 found: NO (tried pkgconfig and cmake)
    meson.build:36:0: ERROR: Dependency "json-glib-1.0" not found, tried pkgconfig and cmake


A full log can be found at /home/santi/deja-dup/builddir/meson-logs/meson-log.txt
make: *** [Makefile:15: configure] Error 1
```

I'm running lubuntu eoan, where deja-dup is updated, or almost. I wanted to know what's going wrong for future reference though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An error of the form

```
Run-time dependency goa-1.0 found: NO (tried pkgconfig and cmake)
```

means that the build is looking for a file named `goa-1.0.pc` (for `pkgconfig`) or `Findgoa-1.0.cmake` file (which isn’t [what a CMake dependency would look like](https://mesonbuild.com/Dependencies.html#cmake), but the build system can’t know that).

To find that on Lubuntu, install `apt-file`, update your `apt` indexes, then run

```
apt-file search goa-1.0.pc
```

This will reveal that you need to install `libgoa-1.0-dev`. For `json-glib-1.0`, the same process will show that you need to install `libjson-glib-dev`.

Install both packages and you should find that those build errors have been fixed.

For a program such as Déjà Dup which is packaged in Debian, you can quickly see the list of required build dependencies by looking [at the `Build-Depends` entry in the `debian/control` file](https://salsa.debian.org/gnome-team/deja-dup/blob/debian/master/debian/control#L10).

Comment: Once the make finishes, that should be it?

Comment: As far as the build goes, yes; if you want to install the software, you’ll need to run `make install`. (But your comment about Lubuntu Eoan suggests you don’t, or am I mistaken?)

Comment: I've been using Linux and apt for 7 years, wasn't aware of apt-file, and is really useful.